# Why does my Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500) "Watch App" template fail?

Tags: watchkit, xcode11

To familiarize myself with the process, before getting real, I tried to build a Watch-only app from the Xcode 11.2.1 template. The build fails when it attempts to copy an item into a file, instead of into a directory. I can hardly believe this isn't something corrupt in my Xcode environment, but it is happening on different Macs.

I created a new project with the "Watch App" template at `~/Development/Watch` and ran `xcodebuild` from that directory.  There is quite a lot of successful work done, but the last command (failing) in the build log is (with `...` representing `~/Development/`):

```
   PBXCp .../Watch/build/Release-watchos/Watch\ WatchKit\ App.app \
         .../Watch/build/Release-iphoneos/Watch.app/Watch/Watch\ WatchKit\ App.app
```

because

```
   error: make directory
          .../Watch/build/Release-iphoneos/Watch.app/Watch/Watch WatchKit App.app: 
      Not a directory
```

It's failing because `.../Watch/build/Release-iphoneos/Watch.app/Watch` is not a directory (nor should it be).  Is this an Xcode bug (I've seen no reference to it from Apple or in Google searchs), or some stupidity on my part?

Answer (score 0):

This is addressed in the [GM Seed of Xcode 11.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/download/). If you are writing a Mac Catalyst app, please also see the [release notes for Xcode 11.2.1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_2_1_gm_seed_release_notes/).

For any other issues you encounter while using Xcode, please file [bug reports](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I am using already Xcode 11.2.1 final release, so I don't think it's addressed there, and the referenced release notes say nothing about this issue.  I'm taking about a stand-alone Apple Watch app, Catalyst isn't involved.  A bug report is in work.

Comment: I checked the Xcode 11.3 Beta Release Notes too .. nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!!  A sneaky one too ..

It fails if you name the project "Watch" .. name it something else, it's OK.

Comment: Reported as bug#:  FB7474537